# Is there any way to set meta tags dynamically in nuxt 3?

Tags: nuxt.js, meta-tags, nuxt3

I'm trying to populate page title and meta tags with dynamic data coming from api for seo purpose. but unable to get it in view-page-source

I've tried useHead, useSeoMeta and useServerSeoMeta with reactive properties. but all these functions called before getting api response. is there any way to get dynamic meta data in view-source-page?

Comment: Do you use SSR?

Comment: Why don't you call `useHead` on api response?

Comment: @BeSterDevelopment, Yes, I'm using ssr

Comment: @MohanadRefaai, useHead is not working inside any method or under any condition.

Answer (score 10):

`useSeoMeta` works for me. Note that values must be functions.

```
<script setup>

const id = route.params.id;
const { data: product } = await useAsyncData(id, () => 
  apiStore.GET_PRODUCT(id),
);

...

useSeoMeta({
  title: () => product.value?.name,
  description: () => product.value?.short_description,
  ogTitle: () => product.value?.name,
  ogDescription: () => product.value?.short_description,
  // and other stuff
});

<script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. This method worked for UseHead hook also.

`useHead({   link: [{ rel: () => t("myLocaleRelValue"), href: () => t("myLocaleHrefValue"), }], });`